# javax.jdo stopped working with App Engine Backend

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am writing a backend using the google app engine. I have three projects using this (One of which was a tutorial) and after installing a number of updates, the

```
import javax.jdo...
```

lines started showing error saying that it could not be resolved. I have tried to google around a bit but haven't had any luck. Is there something I need to include in the buildpath or some other error? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your error messages....

Be aware that the GAE/J SDK now has two sets of .jar files for JDO code. When you use the JDO .jar files you will need to choose which set to use.

If you explore the `lib` and `src` JDK folders you will see what I mean.

Also, beware of just changing your JDO versions from something like:

```
GAE/J DataNucleus plug-in version:   1.0.10
DataNucleus Access Platform version: 1.1.5
JDO version:                         2.3
```

to

```
GAE/J DataNucleus plug-in version:   2.1.2
DataNucleus Access Platform version: 3.1.3
JDO version:                         3.0.1
```

The GAE/J documentation mentions info and precautions.

Comment: I actually found multiple (simple) errors. but yes, this was one. It seems that after the update, instead of picking one, it just didn't define the JDO version, but once I set it to V2, it worked perfectly